# ¿Cómo usar constantes '.equ' en otros archivos ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador, gcc

Tengo en un archivo las siguientes constantes

```
/* --- gpio.s */
.equ GPPUD      148
.equ GPPUDCLK0  152
```

Pero las necesito en otro archivo ensamblador llamado auxiliar.s. Compilo juntos los archivos, pero al usarlas en auxiliar.s me indica que los símbolos no están definidos. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo evitar eso?, es decir que pueda usar las constantes de un archivo en otros archivos fuente.

Comment: `.equ` son como los `#define`s de C, ¿Cómo estás incluyendo los archivos para usar las directivas?

Comment: Utilizo make para compilarlos
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGS=-O2 -g -mfpu=vfpv2 -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -nostartfiles

kernel.img: kernel.elf
 arm-none-eabi-objcopy kernel.elf -O binary kernel.img

kernel.elf: main.s gpio.o auxiliar.o
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) gpio.o auxiliar.o main.s -o kernel.elf

auxiliar.o: auxiliar.s
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c auxiliar.s

gpio.o: gpio.s
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c gpio.s

Comment: Entiendo que estás compilando cada archivo por separado, pero las directivas para el reemplazamiento de texto solo son utilizadas en el mismo archivo donde se definen, te recomiendo separar las directivas `.equ` en un archivo adicional y hacer `include` a ese archivo en los otros que necesitan las constantes.